# Calling a method with ref or out parameters from an anonymous method

Tags: c#, .net

This question is related to [one I asked the other day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995377/delegate-signature-generic-delegate) which I got some good helpful answers from.

I needed to call various web methods with varying signatures in a generic way. I wanted to be able to pass the web method to a method which had a delegate argument but I was unsure how to deal with the varying signatures. The solution was to use lambdas (or anonymous methods as I'm using C#2 at the moment).

This worked nicely until I needed my anonymous method to call a web method with out parameters. You can't do this for reasons [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801147/scope-of-anonymous-methods).

So my question is, other than creating a wrapper method with no ref or out params to call from my anonymous method, is there a easier way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually, you *can* use `ref` and `out` - just not **directly** with the calling method's parameters; you can, however, just copy the values before and after invoking:

```
static void Foo(ref string s, out int i)
{
    string tmpS = s;
    int tmpI = 0; // for definite assignment
    DoIt(delegate { Bar(ref tmpS, out tmpI); });
    s = tmpS;
    i = tmpI;
}
```